# try to end up search filter with react but there is mistake

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my main component for seraching:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

import SearchBar from "./SearchBar";
import SearchList from "./SongList";

const SearchMusic = (props) => {

    const [input, setInput] = useState('');
    const [songListDefault, setSongListDefault] = useState();
    const [songList, setSongList] = useState();

    const fetchData = async () => {
        return await fetch('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=tag.gettoptracks&tag=disco&api_key=c17b1886d9465542a9cd32437c804db6&format=json')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                setSongList(data)
                setSongListDefault(data)
            });
    }

    const updateInput = async (input) => {
        const filtered = songListDefault.filter(song => {
            return song.name.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase())
        })
        setInput(input);
        setSongList(filtered);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData()
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Song List</h1>
            <SearchBar
                input={input}
                onChange={updateInput}
            />
            <SearchList songList={songList}/>
        </div>
    );
};

export default SearchMusic;
```

below is separate input js file:

```
import React from 'react';

const SearchMusic = ({keyword, setKeyword}) => {

    const BarStyling = {width: "20rem", background: "#F2F1F9", border: "none", padding: "0.5rem"};

    return (
        <input
            type="text"
            style={BarStyling}
            key='random1'
            value={keyword}
            placeholder={'Search a song'}
            onChange={(e => setKeyword(e.target.value))}
        />
    );
};

export default SearchMusic;
```

end it is my song list below:

```
import React from 'react';

const SongList = ({songList = []}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {
                songList && songList.tracks.track.map((song, index) => {
                        if (song) {
                            return (
                                <div key={song.name}>
                                    <h1>{song.name}</h1>
                                </div>
                            )
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                )
            }
        </div>
    );
};  
export default SongList;
```

I get this mistake --> TypeError: setKeyword is not a function. I don't what's wrong and don't know how to get rid of it. It seems to me problem is in updateInput function more precisely in what it returns --> song.name.toLowerCase(). There is api link:
http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=tag.gettoptracks&tag=disco&api_key=c17b1886d9465542a9cd32437c804db6&format=json
I need to get name of a song in search input... But something's wrong

Comment: in your post you have never defined the setKeyword function which is passed as props to SearchMusic component. kindly provide that code which is calling the SearchMusic component

Comment: I haven't completely understood how to do it

Comment: Please review your code and check the components names, in order to make it clear what is what. Currently your main component is `SearchMusic`, which has two children (`SearchBar` and `SearchList`); then you say you have a separate input, which seems to be called `SearchMusic` too (as your main component), and a `SongList` component nut none of them seems to be imported into any other component you shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The props that this component are expecting are not getting passed into component in your parent component

```
const SearchMusic = ({keyword, setKeyword}) => {

    const BarStyling = {width: "20rem", background: "#F2F1F9", border: "none", padding: "0.5rem"};

    return (
        <input
            type="text"
            style={BarStyling}
            key='random1'
            value={keyword}
            placeholder={'Search a song'}
            onChange={(e => setKeyword(e.target.value))}
        />
    );
};
```

That is assuming that the following is the above component

```
<SearchBar
                input={input}
                onChange={updateInput}
            />
```

How about

```
<SearchBar
   keyword={input}
   setKeyword={updateInput}
            />
```